# How properly use utf8_decode at Laravel controller json response?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I'm in a struggle working with Laravel JSON response.

What I'm trying to do, is create a CURL request to Laravel controller.

So this is the CURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://dev.laravel/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

... and this is the controller code:

```
$data = array(
    'code' => ($this->code ? $this->code : 0),
    'message' => 'àèìòù',
    'data' => ''
);
return response()->json($data);
```

The problem is the message accentuation . But if I only return an string and use `utf8_decode($output)` the accentuation work as well, here's an example:

```
// curl
echo utf8_decode($output);

// laravel controller
return 'àèìòù';
```

[UPDATE]

Another example that doesn't work:

```
$response = array(
    'code' => 200,
    'message' => 'àèìòù',
    'data' => array()
);
return response()->json($response, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

{"code":200,"message":"Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹","data":[]} // result
```

Comment: Do you use ISO-8859-1 intentionally anywhere in your application flow?

Comment: What exactly is "the problem"? Where are you seeing those mangled characters exactly? Very likely wherever you're *viewing* the result simply does not handle encodings correctly, and/or there is no problem to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, Laravel is using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).Try using the [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)-option:

```
response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

> **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**
>
> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

*See http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php .*

Comment: @Pablo try adding `['Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8']` as the third argument instead.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem before but when I use json_encode() function it worked correctly:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: sorry @ÁlvaroGonzález I just want understand. what do you mean with strange,  and I use Arabic language and there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Anyway , at the cliente side, I had to use:

```
utf8_decode($response['message']);
```

Comment: The first line of code is exactly what Laravel does [behind the scenes](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/JsonResponse.php#L108) - That's Symfony's HTTP framework, which Laravel extends.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8+ allows named parameters

```php
return response()->json($data, options: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```